# Do I have to manually list all sub-directories within <resources> in Java POM

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

my Java Framework has a standard Maven test resources structure that looks like this:

> ```
> src   
>
>    test r
>
>      resources 
>
>        folder1testdata
>
>        folder2testdata
>
>        folder3testdata
> ```

If I just put src/test/resources in my POM, it does NOT find any of my test data. I have to list EVERY resource folder even though they are all sub directores of the standard Maven resource directory. Is this correct or am I missing something?

Thanks
Matt

```
    <testresources>
        <testresource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </testresource>
        <testresource>
          <directory>src/test/resources/folder1testdata</directory>
        </testresource>
        <testresource>
          <directory>src/test/resources/folder2testdata</directory>
        </testresource>
        <testresource>
          <directory>src/test/resources/folder3testdata</directory>
        </testresource>
    </testresources>
```

Comment: I don't think that you should mix the `test` resource with the production resource. That aside, it should be enough to include the most parent folder

Comment: Sorry corrected that. But if I just use the resources parent directory it does not find the data:         <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>

Comment: The question is how you try to find the directories for your test data? `getResourcesAsStream('...')`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to include the sub-folders under `resources` or `testresources` in `pom.xml`. You should use the sub-folder name along with the resource name for accessing the resource under sub-folder.

For example, if you have `test.properties` in `folder1testdata`, you should use `/folder1testdata/test.properties` while accessing the properties file

Comment: Thanks Prasann - yes that makes sense.